# How to load video with json using lightGallery.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

.I do an example embled video: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/examples.html
and i have a problem with json! I can't load video when click image(div json) on website!!
But when I click image(div) slide video load complete and on this slide I can load all video(div and div json) !! Please help me when I click image(div json) video must be load.

this my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post("listvideojson.aspx", function (response) {
            var listlinks = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < listlinks.length; i++) {
                $("#video").append("<div data-src='" + listlinks[i].link + "'><img class='hinh' src='Images/149712_133340426820507_1784820870_n.jpg' /></div>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<link href="CSS/lightGallery.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/lightGallery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This my html body:

```
<div id="video">
    <div data-src="https://vimeo.com/110223381">
        <img class="hinh" src="Images/10156016_399548070182677_8227239214459379074_n.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div data-src="https://vimeo.com/110223326">
        <img class="hinh" src="Images/10156016_399548070182677_8227239214459379074_n.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div data-src="https://vimeo.com/110214790">
        <img class="hinh" src="Images/10156016_399548070182677_8227239214459379074_n.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div data-src="https://vimeo.com/110214789">
        <img class="hinh" src="Images/10156016_399548070182677_8227239214459379074_n.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```